# Node.js multi platform project structure

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline, meanjs

Its really confusing to setup the best project structure for node.js
I'm developing node.js application that works on Browser, Mobile and Desktop.
This application has many modules like billing, support, dashboard etc..

I started with express.js MVC pattern, later Sails.js looked very attractive.
Then came across MEAN Stack and finally landed on Microservices Seneca.js

Micro-Services looks like what i needed, But i see that Sails.js don't support it.
I wanted to use Aerospike NoSQL, but waterline orm doesn't support it right now.

So what is the project structure solution you are using for node.js that works in Browser, Mobile and Desktop?

Comment: I can't make any promises that this will help, this here's a tutorial that implements seneca in an express app - not sails but the concepts should be transferable: https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/deploying-node-app

Comment: The MEAN stack is very good from my experience, but Angular.JS wont be very useful for the mobile and desktop part.

Comment: You can use Sails for building the backend REST API which will communicate with client in JSON only. Then front end you can keep independent from backend. I'm recommending Sails because it has really good project structure out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This is an *highly* subjective question. But [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) is what you are looking for. It does support desktop, browser, mobile, etc. and encourage NoSQL by it's native MongoDB support.

As a reference, I personally did try every single one of the frameworks you have tested (Sails, MEAN, etc.) and ended up with Meteor as my preferred.

As for the project structure, you can read more on various tutorials, [books](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/structure/) and [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCWZ-DNP8cs). The learning curve *is* steep, but the community behind the project is quite alive and helpful.